# How do I push my build directory to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a Node project with some front end that results in a ./build directory. How do I setup Heroku to understand that build is what it needs to operate and not my whole project?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku gets all informations of the node.js app using the package.json that needs to be **on the main path**.Just configure your paths correctly in package.json and it should work fine.